# Weights - Normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the weight of males distributes by normal distribution with $μ=70$ and $σ=5$, and females weight distributes by normal distribution with $μ=60$ and $σ=4$.
The number of woman in the society is $60$%. We checked the weight of $10$ people.

What is the probability that the heaviest person will be more than $80$ kg?

So what I thought is to use standard score for males and females separably (and then to add up the probabilities to be greater than $80$), with $n=6$ for females and $n=4$ for males. But the score I get for males is $1$. So do I need to use other approach?

Comment: How many males are there?

Comment: I edited, the percent was not shown. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note on standard scores: the standard score for males is $\frac{80-70}{5}=2\ne1$. You may wish to review this concept to see why the standard score for females is $5$, a fact we use below.

Let $\Phi$ denote the $N(0,\,1)$ CDF. In kg, a random person's mass $\le80$ with probability $p:=0.6\Phi(5)+0.4\Phi(2)$. The highest of $10$ selected masses $>80$ iff at least one of them is, which has probability $1-p^{10}$. I'll leave you to do the calculations. You should find $p\approx0.991,\,1-p^{10}\approx0.0874$.